# Thorntail: dynamic values on project_defaults.yml

Tags: kubernetes, thorntail

Working with Thorntail/Kubernetes, is it possible to use dynamic values on project_defaults.yml? For example:

```
thorntail:
  ejb3:
    thread-pools:
      default:
        max-threads: ${my.variable}
```

Where `my.variable` will be configured on the dashboard of a specific module.

The idea is to replace standalone.xml values without performing a new deploy every time I need to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

That is in theory possible, because Thorntail is based on WildFly, which allows changing some configuration values without restart. Your example refers to a WildFly configuration value, so it might be possible. Those configuration values in Thorntail that don't come from WildFly don't allow for this at all.

You can use the `management` fraction to let Thorntail expose the WildFly management interface. Then, you can use the WildFly management client (`ModelControllerClient`) to issue management operations. However, I'd discourage you from doing this, as Thorntail isn't really designed for it.

(Also, Thorntail has reached its end of life. See here for more: https://thorntail.io/posts/the-end-of-an-era/)

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by configuring the variable as an environment variable. Using the previous example:

```
thorntail:
  ejb3:
    thread-pools:
      default:
        max-threads: ${env.my_variable:default_value}
```

And then we configure *my_variable* on the dashboard of the desired module.

It is important to notice that we should define a default value, because if that thorntail property is numeric and the environment variable is not defined on the module, we will face a parsing problem since the parser will interpret the variable name as a number. This is a real example:

Kubernets module:

```
RCNT_MAX_THREADS is defined with 12
```

project_defaults.yml:

```
thorntail:
  ejb3:
    thread-pools:
      default:
        max-threads: ${env.RCNT_MAX_THREADS:10}
```

This will cause the application to use max-threads with the value 12. If we don't define RCNT_MAX_THREADS on the module, the value 10 will be used instead.

There is also a very useful option to track what values are really being used: https://docs.thorntail.io/2.5.0.Final/#the-usage-txt-file_thorntail